# requests failes to keep logged in session

Tags: python, parsing, session, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some emails from [mdpi.com](http://www.mdpi.com), emails available only to logged in users. But it fails when I am trying to do so. I am getting 
when logged out:

[image]

Code itself:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import traceback

login_data = {'form[email]': 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'form[password]': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'remember': 1,}
base_url = 'http://www.mdpi.com'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = headers

# log_in
s = session.post('https://susy.mdpi.com/user/login', data=login_data)

print(s.text)
print(session.cookies)


def make_soup(url):
    try:
        r = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        return soup
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None


example_link = 'http://www.mdpi.com/search?journal=medsci&year_from=1996&year_to=2017&page_count=200&sort=relevance&view=default'


def article_finder(soup):
    one_page_articles_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='article-content')
    for article_div in one_page_articles_divs:
        a_link = article_div.find('a', class_='title-link')
        link = base_url + a_link.get('href')
        print(link)
        article_soup = make_soup(link)
        grab_author_info(article_soup)


def grab_author_info(article_soup):

    # title of the article
    article_title = article_soup.find('h1', class_="title").text
    print(article_title)

    # affiliation
    affiliations_div = article_soup.find('div', class_='art-affiliations')
    affiliation_dict = {}
    aff_indexes = affiliations_div.find_all('div', class_='affiliation-item')
    aff_values = affiliations_div.find_all('div', class_='affiliation-name')
    for i, index in enumerate(aff_indexes):  # 0, 1
        affiliation_dict[int(index.text)] = aff_values[i].text

    # authors names
    authors_div = article_soup.find('div', class_='art-authors')
    authors_spans = authors_div.find_all('span', class_='inlineblock')
    for span in authors_spans:
        name_and_email = span.find_all('a')  # name and email
        name = name_and_email[0].text

        # email
        email = name_and_email[1].get('href')[7:]

        # affiliation_index
        affiliation_index = span.find('sup').text
        indexes = set()
        if len(affiliation_index) > 2:
            for i in affiliation_index.strip():
                try:
                    ind = int(i)
                    indexes.add(ind)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        print(name)
        for index in indexes:
            print('affiliation =>', affiliation_dict[index])
        print('email: {}'.format(email))     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    article_finder(make_soup(example_link))
```

What should I do in order to get what I want?

Comment: uh did you put your actual login and password in your code? wouldn't you like to hide them?

Comment: yeah, they were, i edited your question so random people don't have access to your account. you're welcome. maybe you should change your password now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah that is easy, you haven't managed to log in correctly.  If you look at the response from your initial call you will see that you are returned the login page HTML instead of the my profile page.  The reason for this is that you are not submitted the hidden token on the form.

The solution request the login page, and then use either lxml or BeautifulSoup to parse the hidden input 'form[_token]'.  Get that value and then add it to your login_data payload.

Then submit your login request and you'll be in.

Comment: Yep.
Added:
`login_data['form[_token]'] = bs.find('input', id='form__token').get('value')`
and it works.
Thanks.